# Ubuntu Linux set default folder permissions for specific directory?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, webserver

My web server is running on Ubuntu Linux. The user www-data is able to create directories inside the `/data/` directory but the permissions on a newly created directory is 345.

How can I make the default permissions for a directory created by the user www-data in `/data/` 774?

1. The folder owner is www-data and the user group is www-data.
2. I've tried doing the following:

   ```
   sudo setfacl -dR -m g::rwx,u::rwx  /data/ 
   sudo chmod -R 774 /data
   ```
3. Could it be umask related?
4. My `getfacl` output is as follows:

   ```
   getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
   # file: data/
   # owner: www-data
   # group: www-data
   # flags: -s-
   user::rwx
   user:www-data:rwx
   user:ubuntu:rwx
   group::rwx
   mask::rwx
   other::rwx
   default:user::rwx
   default:group::rwx
   default:other::rwx
   ```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My answer would indeed be "umask".  With umask you indicate what permissions should be removed.  In your case, 3.

```
umask 003
```

www-data needs to set that before creating files or directories.

Comment: how would you set umask for specific user "www-data" per directory ? Thanks

Comment: It's not set "per directory".  Once set, it's effective for all new directories and files created.  For a normal user account, you'd set this in his profile.  But www-data is a service user, a daemon.  I suppose we're talking about Apache, httpd?   What process is actually creating the new directories?

Comment: yes it's Apache httpd, and it's using mkdir

Comment: I know Apache rather well, but still don't know how you could do a "mkdir", which is a shell command.  Can you explain?